# Can another column name than "value" be used in Highmaps?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps, field-names

I have a JSON file with multiple columns, and would like to keep the display of any of those as a map relatively open, based on the choice of the user. Now, I can't see any examples of using other column names for display in Highmaps than "value". Is it so? Or is there any way to name within the Javascript code the column that should be used by Highmaps for the display of the data?

That is, the column names are (for example) these:

```
LC_Ctry_Limit,LC_Capita_Limit,LC_Ctry_Footprint,LC_Capita_Footprint,LC_Score
```

Now, in order to be able to display the data from LC_Score, I'd need to rename the column (hard coded into the JSON-file) into "value". Thus:

```
LC_Ctry_Limit,LC_Capita_Limit,LC_Ctry_Footprint,LC_Capita_Footprint,value
```

But what is, if the user wants to display instead another column? Do I need to create five different JSON files, for each column, and name it "value" then? That seems rather inflexible to me.

My Highmaps-code looks like this, based on loading first a GeoJSON and then a JSON file, and I guess there, it should be something about a column-name-specifier:

```
    series : [
    {
        data : data,
        mapData: geojson,
        joinBy: ['Country_40','Country'],
        name: 'LC_Score',
        borderWidth: 0.2,
        COLUMN-TO-BE-USED: lorem
    }]
```

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Your problem is hard to grasp. Maybe it's just me.

Comment: I added some explanations. Perhaps that can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set values of `value` property before setting the data in chart's options/configuration. This selection can be based on value passed into function that will return prepared array for configuration.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bmv0y8dn/

```
    var columnToBeUsed = 'lorem';
    $('#container').highcharts('Map', {
        series: [{
            data: (function (columnToBeUsed) {
                var len = data.length,
                    tab = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    data[i].value = data[i][columnToBeUsed];
                }
                return data;
            })(columnToBeUsed),
            ...
```

Series data can be changed dynamically using [Series.setData](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#Series.setData), so you could change `value`'s value and call setData() with new data for dynamic data change.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot!